# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code - Xcode 14.2

Tags: xcode

I am unable to build/archive the app & I am keep on getting this error on Xcode 14.2. Below are the ways I have tried to fix this error but no luck.

1. In Pods frameworks class, **source="$(readlink "${source}")"** with **source="$(readlink -f "${source}")"**
2. Updated Cocoa-pods to latest version(**1.14.3**)

Also my project contains no run scripts.

[image]